# How do I mock or embed an OSGi HttpService in a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, jetty, osgi

I have a module that I want to unit test, which extends `HttpServlet` and, in the real application is connected to an OSGi `HttpService` (the Jetty-based Pax Web) using `registerServlet()`.

I'm setting up a unit test for that module and want to check whether some test HTTP requests are handled correctly. For this, I need either to embed an instance of `HttpService` from one of my bundle JARs or create a mock. Since I want to process an actual HTTP request, I figured I should really run a HTTP server. So far, I found tutorials on how to run a Jetty instance from within an application, but I still need to wrap the HttpService around this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to wrap a Jetty instance in a simple implementation of `HttpService`.